# Trouble Serializing Enums with JSON4S

Tags: json, scala, serialization, enums, json4s

I have an enum class hierarchy like this:

```
abstract class EnumBase {
  def code: String
}

abstract class EnumObject[EnumT <: EnumBase] {...}
```

I use this in many places. Here is one  example:

```
sealed abstract case class StateCode(code: String) extends EnumBase

object StateCode extends EnumObject[StateCode] {...}
```

I would like to serialize a case class containing `StateCode` deeply nested inside into JSON. I  have written the following custom serializer to do this:

```
class EnumSerializer[EnumT <: EnumBase: scala.reflect.ClassTag](enumObject: EnumObject[EnumT])
  extends org.json4s.Serializer[EnumT] {

  val EnumerationClass = scala.reflect.classTag[EnumT].runtimeClass

  def deserialize(implicit format: Formats):
  PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), EnumT] = {
    case (TypeInfo(EnumerationClass, _), json) => json match {
      ...
    }
  }

  def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
    case i: EnumT => JString(i.code)
    case _ => JString("BLAH")
  }
}
```

This isn't working in that the resulting JSON is merely `"stateCode":{}` when  I  serialize a case class like this:

```
MyClass(id = 123,
        version = 1,
        year = 2016,
        input = MyInput(
          ...
          stateCode = StateCode.CO
        )
 )
```

Note I am using an `Extraction.decompose` on the `MyInput` instance within my  custom deserializer for `MyClass` in the  hope my custom serializer will  kick in there.

I also tried writing a custom serializer dedicated solely to `StateCode` just  to  see if  my attempt to be  generic is the issue. That didn't help either.

Any ideas on how I can get JSON4S to serialize my enums?

Comment: can you provide what is hidden inside "..." and provide your class simplified to show what you actually try to serialize/deserialize

Comment: The "..." inside the companion object simply represents some helper methods for use with all enums--like  converting a string to the corresponding enum. That isn't relevant for serialization. However, I did provide an example of what my original case class looks like and where  my enum lies inside.

Comment: can you also provide "CO" definition? :)

Comment: As implied by the namespace, `CO` is an instance of  `StateCode`, which  subclasses `EnumBase` as shown above.

Comment: It cannot be, StateCode is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

Comment: I said `CO` is an *instance* of `StateCode`, which makes perfect sense. Implementations of abstract classes and even traits [can be instantiated in Scala quite easily](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259168/how-does-curly-braces-following-trait-instantiation-work) without another named concrete type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120545/discussion-between-kpbochenek-and-vidya).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
abstract class EnumBase {
  def code: String
}

abstract class EnumObject[EnumT <: EnumBase] {}

final case class StateCode(code: String) extends EnumBase

object StateCode extends EnumObject[StateCode] {
  val CO = new StateCode("CO")
  val CA = new StateCode("CA")
}

case class ClassWithStateCode(id: Int, x: StateCode)

case class MyClass(id: Int, version: Int, year: Int, co: StateCode)
```

Which doesn't require defining any serializer but this might not be what you are looking for.

Potential issue with what I assume you are doing:

```
object StateCode extends EnumObject[StateCode] {
  val CO = new StateCode("CO") {}
  val CA = new StateCode("CA") {}
}
```

is that you are creating anonymous class which is subtype of StateCode which is `case class` and you should be very careful extending case classes as they might have wrong equals/hashcode.

Answer (score 0):

This works for non-generic version of serializer but I am afraid this might not be possible to make it generic

```
abstract class EnumBase {
  def code: String
}

abstract class EnumObject[EnumT <: EnumBase] {}

sealed abstract case class StateCode(code: String) extends EnumBase

object StateCode extends EnumObject[StateCode] {
  val CO = new StateCode("CO") {}
  val CA = new StateCode("CA") {}
}

case class ClassWithStateCode(id: Int, x: StateCode)

case class MyClass(id: Int, version: Int, year: Int, co: StateCode)

object StateCodeSerializer extends org.json4s.Serializer[StateCode] {

      override def deserialize(implicit format: Formats):
      PartialFunction[(TypeInfo, JValue), StateCode] = {
        case (TypeInfo(EnumerationClass, _), jsonx) => jsonx match {
          case i: JString => new StateCode(i.values) {}
        }
      }

      override def serialize(implicit format: Formats): PartialFunction[Any, JValue] = {
        case i: StateCode => JString(i.code)
      }
    }

    implicit val formats2 = DefaultFormats + StateCodeSerializer

    val testClass = MyClass(2, 0, 1966, StateCode.CO)
    println(write(testClass))
    println(read[MyClass](write(testClass)))
```